# Poster image to amp-youtube

Tags: amp-html

I want to have a poster image for a YouTube video.

So when you click on an image, it will automatically play the YouTube video.

It’s possible?

Thank you !

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The `poster` attribute is not applicable to the `amp-youtube` component, at this time what you're trying to do is not possible.

The following attributes work with the `amp-youtube` component as described [here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-youtube).

- autoplay
- data-videoid
- data-live-channelid
- data-param-* (Passes a data param to the iFrame embed for Youtube)
- credentials

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding an `amp-img` inside of your `amp-youtube` tag.

```
<amp-youtube
  data-videoid="mGENRKrdoGY"
  width="358"
  height="204"
  layout="responsive"
>
  <amp-img
    src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Wm1fWz-7nLQ/hqdefault_live.jpg"
    placeholder
    layout="fill"
  />
</amp-youtube>
```

Documentation found on Google's [amp.dev](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-youtube/).